R - How to automatically feed in parameters from aov() to power.anova.test()
I need to implement an assessment of the statistical power of ANOVA tests into my automated analysis workflow in order to point out in which datasets an ANOVA-analysis bears any statistical relevance, as there usually are very few samples per category.
My intended approach is to automatically feed in everything possible from aov() into power.anova.test() in order to extract the power value.
I think that i have most of what i need figured out already, but some doubt and one issue still remain.
Here is what i assembled so far:
## example data
n <- 5  # n replicates
gs <- factor( c(rep("a",n), rep("b",n), rep("c",n)) )  # groups
vs <- c(rnorm(n,4), rnorm(n,5), rnorm(n,7))  # values
plot(vs ~ gs)  # just for a quick visual impression


## ANOVA
an <- aov(vs ~ gs)
su <- summary(an)
su <- unlist(summary(aov(vs ~ gs)))  

# 'an' and 'su' provide a lot of easily accessible parameters and anova-results for further use


## calculate power of the test

# gather means and variances of groups
groupmeans <- c()
groupvars <- c()
for(i in 1:length(unique(gs))) {
  group <- vs[gs == unique(gs)[i]]
  groupmeans <- c(groupmeans,
                  mean(group) )
  groupvars[i] <- var(group)
}

# test power
pa <- power.anova.test(groups = length(groupmeans),
                 n = n, 
                 between.var = var(groupmeans), 
                 within.var =  sum(groupvars)
                  )

pa$power # this is what i am ultimately interested in

The approach seems to provide all parameters i need for further use, the variables an, su and pa should contain all the information i am interested in. However, i have doubts whether this procedure is correct, especially regarding the variances for within the groups, as supplied to within.var from power.test.anova().
First of all, is the approach generally correct and will it generate the proper input for within.var?
Second, i feel like the input for within.var is probably already included in one of the variables an or su and that i am unnecessarily over-complicating things by not identifying it because i am confused by the terminology. So, can within.var be imported from an or su or generated from the information therein?
It feels like this is a rather simple question, but i am netherless stuck in confusion and after lots of searching i could not find anything about using these two functions together, at least nothing that would clarify the doubts about 'within.var' for my statistically not so experienced mind.
Any suggestions or feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Power is essentially a design parameter.  Once you've actually conducted your experiment, power is somewhat hypothetical: your result is either significant or not.  What might be more informative would be to compare your actual effect with the smallest relevant and minimum detectable differences.

Your within group variance is var(an$residuals), sum(groupvars) will be too large. But I agree with Limey, that this routine is perhaps not a great idea, as it is estimating post-hoc power, which is generally misleading, see e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6738696/.
